# setOnScrollChangeListener on a ScrollView : Error

Tags: android, compiler-errors, scrollview

When an user is at the end of my ScrollView, I want to detect it and load some new items. I have done it, but it appears that function I use doesn't work with some old version of Android.

I have this code :

```
scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
    scrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new ScrollListener(this));
```

then :

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
public class ScrollListener implements View.OnScrollChangeListener {


ScrollingActivity context;

public ScrollListener(ScrollingActivity context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void onScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
    ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) v;
    View view = (View) scrollView.getChildAt(scrollView.getChildCount() - 1);
    int diff = (view.getBottom() - (scrollView.getHeight() + scrollY));
    int oldDiff = (view.getBottom() - (scrollView.getHeight() + oldScrollY));
    // Si on a atteint le bas de la scrollView et qu'on était en train de descendre
    if(diff == 0 && oldDiff > 0) {
        context.endOfScroll(); // function I call to load data...
    }
}}
```

I have this error :

```
08-19 21:27:35.135 26504-26504/com.histoire_horreur E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                              java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.histoire_horreur.Listener.ScrollListener
                                                                  at com.histoire_horreur.MainActivity.createView(MainActivity.java:59)
                                                                  at com.histoire_horreur.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:47)
                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1150)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2315)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:165)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1373)
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5391)
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

As I told, this code works fine for some versions of Android, but for my Wiko 4.2.2 it doesn't.
My error is the same than here : https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/62241/problem-setting-on-scroll-listener-to-android-horizontal-scroll-view-class-not-found-exception
Solution there was to use ViewTreeObserver, however, I don't succeed to detect when scroll is at the bottom. I tried to do this :

```
scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
@Override
public void onScrollChanged() {
// How to get X, Y, Old X and Old Y ?
}
});
```

But I can't get scrollX, scrollY, oldScrollX and oldScrollY.

Do you know a way to make it work on all verisons of Android ?

Answer (score 3):

i have same problem.
if you use ViewTreeObserver the code working correctly with no exception, and only issue is detect when scroll view on the bottom.
this snip code can help you:

```
@Override
public void onScrollChanged() {

    View v = myScrollView.getChildAt(myScrollView.getChildCount() - 1);
    int diff = (v.getBottom() - (myScrollView.getHeight() + myScrollView.getScrollY()));
    if (diff <= 0) {
        //load data here, there is bottom of scrollview
     }
}
```